# Accessing current class through $this-> from a function called statically.

Tags: php, oop

This feels a bit messy, but I'd like to be able to call a member function statically, yet have the rest of the class behave normally...

Example:

```
<?php
class Email
{
    private $username = 'user';
    private $password = 'password';
    private $from     = 'test@example.com';
    public  $to;

    public function SendMsg($to, $body)
    {
        if (isset($this))
            $email &= $this;
        else
            $email = new Email();

        $email->to = $to;

        // Rest of function...
    }
}

Email::SendMsg('mqa@test.com');
```

How best do I allow the static function call in this example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want the static method to be a "shortcut" for:

```
$mail = new Email();
$mail->to = 'somebody@somewhere.com';
$mail->body = 'this is the body';  // this property was not in your example, but assuming...
$mail->Send();
```

Perhaps:

```
// class declaration omitted ...    

static public function SendMsg( $to, $body )
{
    $mailobject = new self;

    $mailobject->to = $to;
    $mailobject->body = $body;
    $mailobject->Send();
}
```

Comment: Exactly that! Don't know why I hadn't thought of using new self. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your method to be `static` you cannot have `$this` keyword *inside* the method.

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

Taken from [PHP: Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Interestingly, it is available but is actually a reference to the calling object. Scary, huh?

Comment: That is interesting, I would have loved to have tested it out if I had a PHP IDE at work but I cannot. :(

Comment: I know you cant access $this in the static method, but I want to be able to also call the method from other methods within the class in other circumstances...

Comment: @MQA: That is not something I have much expertise with, have you tried knittl's proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

make the `SendMsg` a static function, create a private member variable called $email and save a reference to a newly created Email object